# Typecasting on bitwise operators

Tags: php, bit-shift

Can anyone explain why I have different output for the two bitwise operation in the code below?
According to the php documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php, $value should typecast to an integer:

> Both operands and the result for the << and >> operators are always treated as integers.

My code:

```
$value = 4294967295;
echo 'value is float: '  . (($value >> 32 - 1) & 1); //OUTPUT: value is string: 1
$value = '4294967295';
echo 'value is string: ' . (($value >> 32 - 1) & 1); //OUTPUT: value is string: 0
```

Does typecasting for the second operation not work, since unsigned integers aren't supported and the operation is performed on the ASCII values of the characters?
If so, why does it work with the float value?

My code works fine with the float value, so I have no real problem, but I would like to understand what is happening. It took me a while to figure out, where my code didn't behave as expected.

I use php version 5.4.19 on Windows 7 x64 (for testing).

Comment: PHP 5.5.11 (cli) (built: May 30 2014 18:13:30) and OSX gives `1` in both cases

Comment: Cannot reproduce in any version of PHP: http://3v4l.org/IQ1CG

Comment: @deceze I can't either at http://3v4l.org, but http://ideone.com/ , http://codepad.org/ and others produce the same output as I have on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an explanation of what appears to be happening. PHP 5.3.18, windows XP, 32 bit.

The code:

```
$value = 4294967295;        //  This is a 'float'
$vint = (int) $value;      //  this becomes -1 as an integer.

// shows the types and values
var_dump($value, $vint, dechex($vint));
echo 'value is float: '  . (($value >> 32 - 1) & 1); //OUTPUT: value is string: 1
```

The output:

```
float 4294967295
int -1
string 'ffffffff' (length=8)
value is float: 1
```

Note that the 'float' is converted to integer -1, which is all bits on. Hence the output result when shifted.

Now lets look at the other result:

The code:

```
$value = '4294967295'; // is treated as positive?
var_dump($value, dechex($value));
echo 'value is string: ' . (($value >> 32 - 1) & 1); //OUTPUT: value is string: 0
```

The output:

```
string '4294967295' (length=10)
string '7fffffff' (length=8)
value is string: 0
```

The interesting point here is that the 'sign' bit is 'off' when converted to an integer. This explains the output when shifted.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, @ryan . I think the explanation of the operands being treated as integers is kind of ambiguous. It made me loose focus on thinking in binary. In addition I would like to mention 7FFFFFFF is the largest (signed) int possible in php. The typecasting of $value is ceiled to this value.